# Help with changing DropDown event to Radio Button triggers - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, onchange

I have a dropdown in my form (the code was provided) and when the second option (of2) in the drop down is selected, some form elements change. It all works fine.

What I want to be able to do is change the dropdown to two radio buttons instead.

Having the same form changes take place on selection of the second radio button (with the first being selected primarily on page load, by default).

**This is the form code for the dropdown:**

```
<form id="propsearch_res" name="propsearch_res" method="post">
  <select name="sales_rental" id="sales_rental" onChange="onChange(this.form)">
     <option value="S" selected="selected">Properties For Sale</option>
     <option value="L">Properties To Let</option>
  </select>
...
```

**and this is the current javascript which powers the change (and rest of form):**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
  function nongeosearch() {
     document.form1.xstyle.value = "7";
  }
  function onChange(obj) {
    var Current = obj.sales_rental.selectedIndex;
    var n = 1;
  obj.price_low.options.length = 0;
  obj.price_high.options.length = 0;

  if (obj.sales_rental.value == "S")
    {
    setsel(obj,"Any Price","","0");
  setsel(obj,"£30,000","30000",n);n=n+1;
  setsel(obj,"£40,000","40000",n);n=n+1;
  setsel(obj,"£50,000+","",n);n=n+1;
    } else {
     setsel(obj,"Any p/month","","0");
  setsel(obj,"£300","300",n);n=n+1;
  setsel(obj,"£400","400",n);n=n+1;
  setsel(obj,"£500+","",n);n=n+1;
    }    
  }   
  $(document).ready(function() {
     onChange(document.propsearch_res);
  });
  function setsel(obj,val1,val2,n) {
     obj.price_low.options[n] = new Option(val1,val2);
     obj.price_high.options[n] = new Option(val1,val2);
  }
 </script>
```

**This is what I tried with my two radio buttons**
(It didnt work, but I think thats because something needs tweaking in the javascript :S)

```
<input type="radio" id="sales_rental" name="sales_rental" value="S" />
<input type="radio" id="sales_rental" name="sales_rental" value="L" onChange="onChange(this.form)" />
```

I have also tried:

```
<input ...onClick="onChange(this.form)" />
```

...without success.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thank you for reading

====
Still no joy... my radio buttons are now like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="sales_rental" checked value="S" />
<input type="radio" name="sales_rental" value="L" />
```

and the JS with your changes in (hopefully in the right place?):

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function nongeosearch() {
       document.form1.xstyle.value = "7";
    }
    function onChange(obj) {
var n = 1;
obj.price_low.options.length = 0;
obj.price_high.options.length = 0;

if (obj.find("input[name=sales_rental]").val() == "S")
{
         setsel(obj,"Any Price","","0");
    setsel(obj,"£30,000","30000",n);n=n+1;
    setsel(obj,"£40,000","40000",n);n=n+1;
    setsel(obj,"£50,000+","",n);n=n+1;
         } else {
          setsel(obj,"Any p/month","","0");
    setsel(obj,"£300","300",n);n=n+1;
    setsel(obj,"£400","400",n);n=n+1;
    setsel(obj,"£500+","",n);n=n+1;
         }    
    }        
    $(document).ready(function() {
        onChange(document.propsearch_res);
    });
    function setsel(obj,val1,val2,n) {
       obj.price_low.options[n] = new Option(val1,val2);
       obj.price_high.options[n] = new Option(val1,val2);
    }
</script>
```

**Original Form Code** (replace first drop down with 2 radio buttons)

```
        <form id="propsearch_res" name="propsearch_res" method="post" action="script_search.php"> 
            <fieldset><legend>Property Search Type</legend> 
                 <span><span id="propsearch1"> 
                    <label for="sales_rental"><img src="images/ico_search.png" alt="Property Search: Step 1" />Search:</label> 
                    <select name="sales_rental" id="sales_rental" onChange="onChange(this.form)"> 
                        <option value="S" selected="selected">Properties For Sale</option> 
                        <option value="L">Properties To Let</option> 
                    </select> 
                 </span></span> 
            </fieldset> 
            <p>Filter search by particulars</p> 
            <fieldset><legend>Search Particulars</legend> 
                <div id="propsearch2">                          
                    <div> 
                        <label for="PropTypwfld"><img class="house" src="images/ico_house.png" alt="Property Search: Step 2" />Search for a:</label> 
                        <select name="type" id="PropTypefld" size="1"> 
                            <option value="">Property</option> 
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.housescape.org.uk/cgi-bin/ptype.pl?ren1"></script> 
                        </select> 
                    </div> 
                    <div> 
                        <label for="area">loacted in:</label> 
                        <select name="area" id="area" size="1"> 
                            <option value="">All Areas</option> 
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.housescape.org.uk/cgi-bin/arealist.pl?ren1"></script> 
                        </select> 
                    </div> 
                    <div> 
                        <label for="Bedroomsfld">with a minimum:</label> 
                        <select name="num_beds" id="Bedroomsfld" size="1">                          
                            <option value="1">1 Bedroom</option> 
                            <option value="2">2 Bedrooms</option> 
                            <option value="3">3 Bedrooms</option> 
                            <option value="4">4 Bedrooms</option> 
                            <option value="5">5 Bedrooms</option> 
                            <option value="6">6 Bedrooms</option> 
                            <option value="">No Preference</option> 
                        </select> 
                    </div>                   
                    <div> 
                        <label for="price_low">between:</label> 
                        <select name="price_low" id="price_low" size="1"></select> 
                    </div> 
                    <div> 
                        <label for="price_high">and:</label> 
                        <select name="price_high" id="price_high" class="lastinput" size="1"></select> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </fieldset> 
            <fieldset class="controls"> 
                <input name="xstyle" id="xstyle" type="hidden" value="" /> 
                <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" onClick="nongeosearch()" value="Search Properties" /> 
            </fieldset> 
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form: change the `select` element to this.

```
<label for="sales_rental0">Properties For Sale</label><input type="radio" id="sales_rental0" name="sales_rental" value="S" checked />
<label for="sales_rental1">Properties To Let</label><input type="radio" id="sales_rental1" name="sales_rental" value="L" />
```

change `$(document).ready` to this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    onChange(document.propsearch_res);

    $("input[name=sales_rental]").click(function(){
        onChange(document.propsearch_res);
    });
});
```

then you should also remove the `id` in your radio button since `id` is unique and remove the onChange event on the radio button.

For your `onChange` function change to this.

```
function onChange(obj) {
    var n = 1;
    obj.price_low.options.length = 0;
    obj.price_high.options.length = 0;

    if (getRadioButtonValue(obj.sales_rental) == "S")
    {
        setsel(obj,"Any Price","","0");
        setsel(obj,"£30,000","30000",n);n=n+1;
        setsel(obj,"£40,000","40000",n);n=n+1;
        setsel(obj,"£50,000+","",n);n=n+1;
    } else {
        setsel(obj,"Any p/month","","0");
        setsel(obj,"£300","300",n);n=n+1;
        setsel(obj,"£400","400",n);n=n+1;
        setsel(obj,"£500+","",n);n=n+1;
    }    
}
```

Lastly add this function in your script.

```
function getRadioButtonValue(radio) {
    if(radio.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0; i<radio.length; i++) {
            if(radio[i].checked) {
                return radio[i].value;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

For the scripts dropdown menu's don't put the `<scripts>` inside the `<select>` tag.

Comment: @rob - thanks for the reply Rob! I cant seem to get it working though.. ive removed the ID's off both radios, taken out the onChange event on the second radio (the one I want to be the trigger) and inserted your javascript in the JS but it doesnt seem to do anything?

Comment: since you are passing the entire form during onChange I also passed the entire form.  I'm not sure if the previous onChange code will work but I have provided some changes on the `onChange`

Comment: Ive updated the above (see the bottom of main post), let me know if ive not put your changes in correctly? Many many thanks!

Comment: can you also post the entire form?

Comment: Original form code added (note, this code does not include any changes, and features the original (first) dropdown which I would like to replace with the two radio buttons)

Comment: Rob, thank you so much. That's excellent and works a treat. Thank you!!

Comment: ...is there anything I can do about the validation on W3C? There are 3 errors on this line "for(var i=0; i<radio.length; i++) {" in the JS script, and errors where javascript is used in the SELECT inputs (to populate the drop down lists), eg: 
 <select name="type" id="PropTypefld" size="1">
      <option value="">Property</option>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.housescape.org.uk/cgi-bin/ptype.pl?ren1"></script>
 </select>

Comment: @rob - When i take the <scripts> outside of the Select tab they break the form. The dropdowns do not become populated (with options) and instead the 'options' appears as plain text wherever the script is located.

Comment: Any ideas on this? I realise its secondary to the question but if we can try something else or solve it that would be perfect? Many many thanks once again

Comment: Could you please help to solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595547/convert-dropdown-to-selection-boxes-with-color