# Convert dropdown to selection boxes with color and trigger drop down action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please help to convert this drop down to selection box with color like white box, black box etc [not check box] .

[image]

So that page is loading , instead of showing drop down I need to show color selection boxes, please help.

I tried some code but it is only partially working .

```html
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">
        <label for="pa_available-colors">Available Colors</label>
      </td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_available-colors" class="" name="attribute_pa_available-colors" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_available-colors">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Choose an option</option>
          <option value="black" class="attached enabled" selected="selected">Black</option>
          <option value="white" class="attached enabled" selected="selected">White</option>
          <option value="red" class="attached enabled" selected="selected">Red</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please help .Please see the following picture , I need to convert drop down to this type of boxes 
[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want a [colorpicker](http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/ctkY3/)

Comment: Selection box with color

Comment: like http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYnsP.jpg

Comment: @Pugaz Friend, really thank you for your effort .  Please see my question now . Also , could you please write code based on my html code

Comment: How about using `radio` instead? [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppan0c1k/)

Comment: Please see the html code

Comment: off topic : 50 rep equals to 20$.. :)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/VVclW0?p=preview have checked this link ?

Comment: Really thank you friend . :) . Could you please make with the given html

Comment: @Manik i have given ans please look into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this code will help you that you want to do

Html

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">
        <label for="pa_available-colors">Available Colors : </label>
      </td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_available-colors" class="" name="attribute_pa_available-colors" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_available-colors">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Choose an option</option>
          <option value="black" class="attached enabled">Black</option>
          <option value="white" class="attached enabled">White</option>
          <option value="red" class="attached enabled">Red</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.selectbox>span {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.selectbox {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selectbox.active {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

JQuery

```
$("#pa_available-colors option").each(function() {
  //get values of all option
  var val = $(this).val();

  //do magic create boxes like checkbox
  $("td.value").append('<div class="selectbox" data-color="' + val + '"><span style="background-color:' + val + '"></span></div>');

});
//remove empty selectbox
$('.selectbox[data-color=""]').remove();

//change select box on click
$(".selectbox").click(function() {
  //remove selected from others
  $(".selectbox").removeClass("active");
  //do active to selected
  $(this).addClass("active");
  //get value
  var optVal = $(this).data("color");

  $("#pa_available-colors").val(optVal) 

});

//change select box on dropdown change
$("#pa_available-colors").change(function(){
    var optVal = $(this).val();
  $(".selectbox").removeClass("active");
  $(".selectbox[data-color='"+optVal+"']").addClass("active");
})
```

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12uax7cv/6/)

Comment: Yes , This is the one i really wanted .

Comment: But in fiddle you missed this   <option value="" selected="selected">Choose an option</option>  . please tell what happen when this is also in the code ?

Comment: Actually my code is work on behalf of this select box option if you add the above option u will see the blank option

Comment: In this case u need to filter blank value or just remove them

Comment: and here is the solution what u need https://jsfiddle.net/12uax7cv/2/ remove empty checkbox

Comment: oh its mean i have saved your 20$ @Manik :)

Comment: Hi, instead of hiding list from drop down , could you please make this like user can select both color box and drop down . Currently on load only one item come in drop down and in drop down at a time only one item is visible . When clicking the other color then drop down showing that color only . Could you please make it like in drop down also i need to show all color .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109503/discussion-between-manik-and-ismail-farooq).

Comment: When i am commenting var selected = $(this).not(":selected").remove();  then the drop down list is repeating  .
Also there is an action take place in drop down changes . Could you please trigger the drop down action to color box also . Is it possible ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109522/discussion-between-manik-and-ismail-farooq).

Answer (score 4):

## Using dropdown list:

Answer is simple: **you can't**.

Let me explain why. The answer for this question is also really, really simple: [MSDN on option tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877(v=vs.85).aspx). You can see there this paragraph:

> Except for background-color and color, style settings applied through the style object for the option element are ignored. In addition, style settings applied directly to individual options override those applied to the containing select element as a whole.

Of course you can convert your dropdown list to [something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974217/convert-dropdowns-to-radio-buttons-w-o-modifying-html) (it's even in *linked* questions... don't be **that** lazy), but is it still dropdown list then? See next part of the answer for more information on using e.g. `radio` element.

## Using something else:

As a workaround you can try making it with, for example, `radio` element:

```css
/* General stuff - radio button. */
input[type="radio"] {
  position: relative;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked:before {
  border: 1px solid #111;
}
/* The "background" - white background with gray border. */
input[type="radio"]:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
/* The "foreground" - color "square". */
input[type="radio"]:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
/* Colours */
input[type="radio"][value="red"]:after {
  background: #c44;
}
input[type="radio"][value="green"]:after {
  background: #4c4;
}
input[type="radio"][value="blue"]:after {
  background: #44c;
}
```

```html
Colour:
<div class="list">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="green">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue">
</div>
```

Here is fiddle with hiding (submenu-like): https://jsfiddle.net/sts77L2h/

With some additional work you should be able to make it work more like dropdown list. Or you can experiment with it to get any result you can imagine.

Obviously you can also try using other elements than `radio` or even look (I don't know any at the time of writing) for a completed and working framework providing such `form` elements.

## TD;DR:

Converter from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974217/convert-dropdowns-to-radio-buttons-w-o-modifying-html) merged with my CSS: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d71jt2us/).

Adapt this solution to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Use HTML5 `input` with `type="color"`, here is example:

In options list you can specify list of colors that you want to see.

```html
 <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="label">
            <label for="pa_available-colors">Available Colors</label>
          </td>
          <td class="value">
           <input type="color" id="pa_available-colors" name="attribute_pa_available-colors" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_available-colors" list="colors">
 <datalist id="colors">
  <option>#ff0000</option>
  <option>#0000ff</option>
  <option>#00ff00</option>
  <option>#ffff00</option>
  <option>#00ffff</option>
 </datalist>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I want to change drop down to boxes like radio , but with color . Please use my given html

Answer (score 1):

Here is the CSS:

```css
select option[value="black"]{
   color:#fff;
    background: black;
}

select option[value="white"]{ 
color:#000;
    background: white;
}
select option[value="red"]{
   color:#fff;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">
        <label for="pa_available-colors">Available Colors</label>
      </td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_available-colors" class="" name="attribute_pa_available-colors" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_available-colors">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Choose an option</option>
          <option value="black" class="attached enabled" selected="selected">Black</option>
          <option value="white" class="attached enabled" selected="selected">White</option>
          <option value="red" class="attached enabled" selected="selected">Red</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But, I suggest that you just add `selected="selected"` to only `value=""`.

Comment: I want to change drop down to boxes like radio , but with color . Please use my given html

Comment: Search "radio button design" in google then edit your radio buttons as the results.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

Using your HTML.

See [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jabuka/rydhd97h/)

**Original**

You can convert your select to radios with some JavaScript. Then use some CSS to handle presentation of that resultant HTML.

Gets transformed from this;

```
<div class="value">
  <select id="pa_available-colors" class="" name="attribute_pa_available-colors" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_available-colors">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="black" class="attached enabled" selected="selected">Black</option>
    <option value="white" class="attached enabled">White</option>
    <option value="red" class="attached enabled">Red</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

To this;

```
<div class="value">
  <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa_available-colors" value="">
  <label for="attribute_pa_available-colors">Choose an option</label>

  <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa_available-colors" value="black" checked="checked">
  <label for="attribute_pa_available-colors">Black</label>

  <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa_available-colors" value="white">
  <label for="attribute_pa_available-colors">White</label>

  <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa_available-colors" value="red">
  <label for="attribute_pa_available-colors">Red</label>
</div>
```

See [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jabuka/rydhd97h/) here

Comment: I want to change drop down to boxes like radio , but with color . Please use my given html

Comment: With your given HTML you have all 3 options selected - is this intentional? Given that you want your selects to behave like a radio this doesn't seem right. Unless you're trying to transform HTML that already exsits.

Comment: Okay that's what I provided in my latest fiddle, unless I am missing something? Did you want me to update the styles to reflect codecanyon example?

Comment: Yes . Could you please do .

Comment: See updated [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jabuka/rydhd97h/) with styling in place.

Comment: Could you please check this friend . I cannot see any changes in fiddle

Comment: Apologies - set my Fiddle to base accidentally, so probably cached. See [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jabuka/rydhd97h/257/)