# Html Select -> Option, Selected color as value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am filling a Html Select by Script. Two of my Selections are Colorpickers. When u pick a number of a NumberSelection, you can see the selected Number at the top of the Select.

How can this work with colors? I know, you can't fill colors in there. But is there a way to show the selected color?

I thought about writing in an "A" and colorize it.

So my Code would look this way:

```
function FillFontColorMenu() {
  FillSelection(GetPossibleColors(), "fontColorMenu"); // Fill the selection with Colors
}

function FillBackgroundColorMenu() {
  FillSelection(GetPossibleColors(), "backgroundColorMenu");
}

function FillSelection(possibleValues, elementId){ // Start filling

        var optionElement; // One option element

        for(var j = 0; j < possibleValues.length; j++) // Create the option elements
        {
          optionElement = "<option id="+"selectionColor"+[j]+elementId+" value='" + possibleValues[j] + "'>"+ "A" +"</option>";  // Create the element string + ! Colorize the "A"-value ! 

          $('#'+elementId).append(optionElement);       // Create                   

          $('#selectionColor'+[j]+elementId).css("background-color", possibleValues[j]); // Give it a Color
        }
}}

function GetPossibleColors() { // Get all possible Colors for the selection
  var possibleColors = [];

possibleColors.push("#" + "123456".toString(16)); // TEST
possibleColors.push("#" + "789963".toString(16));
possibleColors.push("#" + "147852".toString(16));

  return possibleColors;
}
```

I would just need to colorize the "A" of the element string. Any ideas?

You can see an example here: https://ibin.co/3CSP15pLpLmj.png

Comment: Looking for this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36688166/2724173

Comment: Hm not directly. I almost got it, I just need to colorize the selected element at the top of the Selection. You can see a picture of it here: https://ibin.co/3CSP15pLpLmj.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can colorize the selected element at the top of the selection by simpy doing:

```js
$('#fontColorMenu option').each(function(index,item){
    $(item).css('background-color',$(this).val());//Colorize the items
})
$('#fontColorMenu').select().change(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color',$(this).val());//Colorize the box
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fontColorMenu">
  <option value="0">Select...</option>
  <option value="#FF0000">#FF0000</option>
  <option value="#00FF00">#00FF00</option>
  <option value="#0000FF">#0000FF</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Changed `color` to `background-color` as in the image that you gave.